# Spring and hibernate: query.list() does not get executed more than twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class in java with two more methods similar to the one here.

```
 public Object noOfEmployees() {

        List<Employee> emp = null;
        String u = user.getUserName();

        if ("user1".equals(u)) {

            Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession()
                    .createSQLQuery("select * from employee where job='System Analyst'")
                    .addEntity(EMPLOYEE.class);

            emp = query.list();

             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().close();

        } else if ("user2".equals(u)) { 

            Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession()
                    .createSQLQuery("select * from employee where job='DBA'")
                    .addEntity(EMPLOYEE.class);

            emp = query.list();
             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().close();

        } 
        return emp.size();
    }
```

When I ran the application, this is how I got the output:

1. Logged in as 'user2'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='DBA'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='DBA' and rank='2'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where present='yes'
2. Logged in as 'user1'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='System Analyst'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='System Analyst' and rank='3'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where present='yes'
3. Again, logged in as 'user2', first two methods get executed.

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='DBA'

   Hibernate: select * from employee where job='DBA' and rank='2'
4. When I logged in as any user, this time even the first method did not get executed.

I have noticed that the code gets stuck when **query.list()** is encountered. I know that using hibernateTemplate is not recommended but the entire application is written using it. I have only started to learn about spring and hibernate. I will start making changes once I get comfortable with those.

Any suggestions related to the performance of query.list() and ways to improve the code are more than welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: could you please explain what you mean when you say query.list() gets stuck?

Comment: The console did not print anything after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is flawed on many levels... For starters you shouldn't be using `HibernateTemplate` unless you are in a very old application, else use a plain `SessionFactory`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight for more information.

Second when using Spring use Spring to manage your resources, i.e. `Session` in this case, or if you want to do it yourself at least manage it properly!.

So in short use a `SessionFactory` and use `getCurrentSession` instead of `openSession`. And use a proper query.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sf;

@Transactional
public Long noOfEmployees() {
    final String query = "select count(*) from employee where job=:job";
    Query q = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    if ("user1".equals(u)) {
        q.setParameter("job", "System Analyst");
    } else if ("user2".equals(u) ) {
        q.setParameter("job", "DBA");
    }
    return (Long) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

The `@Transactional` will make spring manage the resources, assuming you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your context and properly added the `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: Instead of using SQL I strongly suggest reading up on Hibernate and how to use HQL. Because you are trying to do the things that hibernate already does for you , y9ou are basically working around hibernate instead of with hibernate.

Comment: Thank you very much @v.ladynev and @M.Deinum! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, obviously, with this code

```
Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().

...
getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().close();
```

With this `getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().close()` you get a new session and close it!

You should use HQL

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where job='System Analyst'");
List<Employee> emp = query.list();
```

And the way you use `Hibernate Template` is entirely incorrect.

Refer how to use it

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html

An example

```
public class ProductDaoImpl {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(final String category) throws DataAccessException {
        return this.hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
                criteria.add(Expression.eq("category", category));
                criteria.setMaxResults(6);
                return criteria.list();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mahi You use a complex example. I update with more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change my flawed-on-many-levels code to some extent. All thanks to @M.Deinum and @v.ladynev for their swift responses.

Given below are only snippets where changes to move from HibernateTemplate to SessionFactory are mentioned:

```
//IndexService

    @Transactional
    public class IndexService {

        User user;
        SessionFactory sf;

        public IndexService(User user, SessionFactory sf) {

            this.user = user;
            this.sf = sf;
        }

    //This method is used to get the number of employees based on users.

    public Object noOfEmployees() {

        String u = user.getUserName();

        final String query = "select count(*) from employee where job=:job";

        Query q = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query);

        if ("user1".equals(u)) {

            q.setParameter("job", "System Analyst");

        } else if ("user2".equals(u) ) {

            q.setParameter("job", "DBA");

        }
        return q.uniqueResult();
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Index

    @Controller
    @Transactional
    public class Index {

        @Autowired
        User user;
        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sf;

        @RequestMapping("/index")
        public ModelAndView getIndex() {

            System.out.println("user.getUserName() In Index = " + user.getUserName());

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");

            IndexService indexService = new IndexService(user, sf);

            modelAndView.addObject("noOfEmployees", indexService.noOfEmployees());

            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //spring-servlet.xml

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <bean id="basicDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name"></property>
            <property name="username" value="user"></property>
            <property name="password" value="password"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSource"></property>

            <property name="mappingResources" value="myBeans.hbm.xml" />

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Issues that I came across while changing from HibernateTemplate to SessionFactory:

1.NullPointerException for SessionFactory

In index class,

@Autowired
SessionFactory sf;

and passed it as an argument.

IndexService indexService = new IndexService(user, sf);

2.No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

I put @Transactional above Index also. It is the controller in my application.

Thank you once again @M.Deinum and @v.ladynev!